# Recipients complain they receive Text Message from me with a half hour delay

Tags: sms

I have a G2 w/ Android 2.2 on T-Mobile and Some of my friends complain that they receive Text Message with a half hour delay. One friend is on T-Mobile and one is on ATT so I'm not sure if it's a network, sim card issue, phone issue, android issue, or if it's just their phone....

How can my friends fix this issue? New SIM card?

Comment: Is this just a one-time occurence?  It's probably a temporary network issue; SMSes get delated all the time.

Comment: Even if it's not a one-time thing I still concur with Matthew Read, my wife and I are both on Verizon with a Droid and a Droid 2 (R2-D2 edition!) and sometimes our texts between one another are delayed or duplicated for seemingly no reason, but it's intermittent and rare.

Comment: Gotta concur with @Matthew and @JonnyP. SMS is pretty unreliable.

Comment: I think it's a carrier issue.

Comment: Also, I have friends who insist they'll never use AT&T again because AT&T takes too long to deliver SMS. So maybe it's not an issue that is unique to any one carrier.

Comment: @Amanda - I had that exact issue when I was on my parent's family plan years ago (they've been on AT&T since before they merged with Cingular) and I couldn't wait to get off AT&T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a point a couple of years ago where I had persistent problems with SMSs not being delivered, or being delivered hours late to one particular person. That person was my girlfriend at the time, so you can imagine how well it went down that I seemed to be ignoring her all the time. After much backwards and forwards with the network they ended up issuing us both with new SIM cards and we never saw the problem again.

SMS was never originally designed to be used the way that we all use it today, and is unreliable, but if this keeps happening bug your network and they may be able to do something to help.

Comment: I'd love to know if getting a new SIM card helps you out!

Comment: @Amanda, yeah i told the other person to get a SIM card and it helped. I also upgraded to the G2 :)