# New messages do not show up immediately - HTC Desire Z

Tags: notifications, sms

Has anybody else encountered this problem? I go into my message inbox and at that point I see I have unread text messages that were received many hours before without notification.

I have got the notifications configured appropriately to alert me to new text messages in the status bar. This is an intermittent problem.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else is having the issue still, my phone recently picked up the Gingerbread release. This appears to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Other folks here have suggested that the issue may be with your SIM card:

- [Recipients complain they receive Text Message from me with a half hour delay](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/recipients-complain-they-receive-text-message-from-me-with-a-half-hour-delay)

I was having a similar problem which was resolved when I reset my phone to factory settings (for other reasons). It might be worth asking your carrier for a new SIM, though.

PS. This user asked about [sms receipt delays](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/recipients-complain-they-receive-text-message-from-me-with-a-half-hour-delay) -- a different but related question.

Comment: Could you link to the other answer(s) where a SIM card issue was suggested?

Comment: I did link to the one, but I made that more explicit. I can't find others (though I did discover a lot of tag synonyms ...)